# Forecasting model - Scale mismatch

Tags: forecasting, dataset, prediction, scales

I have the following data:

[image]

As you can see I want to create a regression model, which forecasts a variable, which I have also on a quartely basis.

However, my volume is only on yearly basis.

Is it possible to still predict my "forecasting" variable on a quaterly basis?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to determine if volume and price have a relationship?

This is problematic if you are trying to estimate the demand curve or the supply curve, because they are not isolated in this example. Is the volume high because of rushing production to sell at a high price? Or is the volume high because people are pulling products off the shelf.  I sense you are about to get more than you bargained for in complexity.

Not to be trite, but I think you will also need more data before you run a regression here.

Comment: Thx for your answer! The actual dataset has 24 variables. I just picked out 1 which is problematic to me regarding its scale(Volume). All other variables are on a quarterly basis. However, I still  want to  use it in my model! Any suggestion?

Comment: First, the econometric problems of volume<->price are relatively sophisticated. Your coefficient on the volume variable will be biased by an unknown amount an unknown direction, unless you you can credibly attribute the change in either price or volume to exclusively one source or another.  

If all other variables are quarterly, you can simply say "average sales per quarter"- year 1986 has an average of 25 sales per quarter.

If you have 24 variables, however, there is not enough data to get significance. As a personal rule of thumb, you want about 21 observations per variable for OLS.

Comment: Thx for your tips on the OLS. However, I am still quite unsure about the scale problem? Any recommendation, how to use the yearly data with quaterly data?